# Custom functions in Excel error evaluating false part of IIF

Tags: excel, vba, office365, user-defined-functions

Below is my custom functions in Excel.

```
Function DISCOUNT(c1, r1, k1)

    Dim res
    res = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c1, r1, 2, False)
    DISCOUNT = IIf(Not (IsError(res)), res, k1)
 
End Function
```

In above function, **falsepart** of `IIf` is not working. It gives **#VALUE!** instead of the desired value `t`

What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: `Application.VLookup()` without `WorksheetFunction` will not cause a runtime error if no match is made, but instead returns an error value to `res`.  The rest of your code should then work OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function DISCOUNT(c1, r1, k1)
  Dim res
  DISCOUNT = k1 'assign default value
  On Error Resume Next 'ignore runtime error if match is not found
  res = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c1, r1, 2, False)
  If Err.Number = 0 Then DISCOUNT = res 'match is found
End Function
```

To stay with `IIf` function use [late bound](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2021/02/15/worksheetfunction-and-errors/):

```
Function DISCOUNT(c1, r1, k1)
  Dim res
  res = Application.VLookup(c1, r1, 2, False)'Late Bound: Errors are Values
  DISCOUNT = IIf(Not (IsError(res)), res, k1)
End Function
```